# fix keyerror in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to create new columns with the name 'Absolute_x' and 'Absolute_y'.
The values from these columns are calculate from another column and a formule.

df_train is a dataframe but when i use df_train[index]['Absolute_x] i get the valueError: Incompatible indexer with Series. So i checked the type of df_train and as you can see its a dataframe. So i tried with .set_value this gives me a diffrent error this says index 0 doesn't exist but when i check my indexes from my dataframe it clearly says that it does.

Is there something i'm missing?

```
rangeValues = {'gang': {"x_min" : 0.4, "x_max": 0.6, "y_min": 0, "y_max": 1}, 'lab1': {"x_min" : 0.6, "x_max": 0.1, "y_min": 0.09, "y_max": 0.3}}


df_train['Absolute_x'] = 0
df_train['Absolute_y'] = 0
print(df_train.index)
print(type(df_train))
print(type(df_train[1]['Absolute_x']))
for index, row in df_train.iterrows():
    oldValueX = df_train['Location_X']
    oldValueY = df_train['Location_Y']
    oldMin = 0
    oldMax = 1
    location = row['Location']
    newMaxX = rangeValues[location]['x_max']
    newMinX = rangeValues[location]['x_min']
    newMaxY = rangeValues[location]['y_max']
    newMinY = rangeValues[location]['y_min']
    #df_train.set_value(index, 'Absolute_x',(((oldValueX - oldMin) * (newMaxX - newMinX)) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMinX)
    #df_train.set_value(index, 'Absolute_y', (((oldValueY - oldMin) * (newMaxY - newMinY)) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMinY)
df_train.head()
```

Value from the dataframe :

[image]

### Edit

I tried now with the at method from pandas.

```
import traceback

df_train['Absolute_x'] = 0
df_train['Absolute_y'] = 0
traceback.print_exc(df_train.at[1, 'Absolute_x'])

for index, row in df_train.iterrows():
   oldValueX = df_train['Location_X']
   oldValueY = df_train['Location_Y']
   oldMin = 0
   oldMax = 1
   location = row['Location']
   newMaxX = rangeValues[location]['x_max']
   newMinX = rangeValues[location]['x_min']
   newMaxY = rangeValues[location]['y_max']
   newMinY = rangeValues[location]['y_min']
   #df_train.at[index, 'Absolute_x'] = (((oldValueX - oldMin) * (newMaxX - newMinX)) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMinX
   #df_train.at[index, 'Absolute_y'] = (((oldValueY - oldMin) * (newMaxY - newMinY)) / (oldMax - oldMin)) + newMinY
df_train.head()
```

output :

[image]

Comment: What do you expect `df_train[1]['Absolute_x']` to return in terms of rows/columns of the overall DataFrame?

Comment: I expect the value from the column 'Absolute_x' from row 1. I used that line to test if it had a problem with .set_value or my dataframe.

Comment: Just had to make sure. Have you tried `df.loc`? I think it solves the problem you have. For example, `df.loc[1, 'Absolute_x']`.

Comment: i tried tthis aswell. When i use loc i get the Incompatiable indexer with series error.

Comment: @TomDalton i removed the picture

Comment: If the data is not sensitive, you should include the result of `df_train.head()`.

Comment: I am cannot reproduce any of your issues, except the one from `df_train[1]['Absolute_x']` which, as I stated on my comment about .loc, is a misuse of pandas indexing. For any issues you have, provide the _full traceback in text format_. The error tells us _what_ is wrong, the traceback tells us _where_ it is wrong.

Comment: @brentertainer i tried it now with at[index, column] i now get a new error. See edit

Comment: @MaximeCallebaut I still do not see an error. From your screenshot, I can only see that there was no error (i.e. `None`) from using `.at`.